# How to do a comparison against a given value which doesn't matches using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

New to scripting language, have issue using enums with if else statement in typescript. As an alternative, I am using switch case instead of if else condition

I tried !==, !=== which doesn't seem to work. The first index of enum doesn't work unless I make it, if condition not equal to compared value

```
public static async getElementByLocatorType(locatorType: customLocators, locatorValue: string, expectedText?: string) {
        if (locatorType! === customLocators.CSS) {
            return  element(by.css(locatorValue));
        } else if (locatorType === customLocators.XPATH) {
            return element(await by.xpath(locatorValue));
        } else if (locatorType === customLocators.CSSTEXT) {
            return  element(by.cssContainingText(locatorValue, expectedText));
        } else if (locatorType === customLocators.LINKTEXT) {
            return  element(by.linkText(locatorValue));
        } else if (locatorType === customLocators.BUTTONTEXT ) {
            return  element(by.buttonText(locatorValue));
        } else if (locatorType === customLocators.PARTIALBUTTONTEXT) {
            return  element(by.partialButtonText(locatorValue));
        } else if (locatorType === customLocators.PARTIALLINKTEXT ) {
            return  element(by.partialLinkText(locatorValue));
        } else {
            logger.info('Cannot find any locator listed above');
        }

    }


 export enum customLocators {
     'CSS', 'XPATH', 'CSSTEXT', 'LINKTEXT', 'BUTTONTEXT', 'PARTIALBUTTONTEXT', 'PARTIALLINKTEXT'
 }
```

No element found (by.css) other elements work perfectly fine except (first index of enum)
locatorType === customLocators.CSS

Comment: please remove `!` from first `if` condition

Comment: What is the value of `locatorType` you are passing to the function? Also strict inequality operator is `!==` not `!===`.

Comment: You should really change this to a switch statement. It would be way easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil for the suggestion. !== worked and the error is gone. Its a problem with enums being used especially '0' index of enum doesn't seem to work well unless I make it (Not equals to compared value). 
  If not using enums then (locatorType: string)
  locatorType ==='CSS'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, I used switch case as an alternative which works fine.

```
  public static async  getElementByLocatorType(locatorType: customLocators, 
    locatorValue: string, expectedText?: string) {
            switch (locatorType) {
                case customLocators.CSS:
                   return  element(by.css(locatorValue));
                    break;
                case customLocators.XPATH:
                    return element(by.xpath(locatorValue));
                    break;
                case customLocators.LINKTEXT:
                    return element(by.linkText(locatorValue));
                    break;
                case customLocators.BUTTONTEXT:
                    return element(by.buttonText(locatorValue));
                    break;
                case customLocators.CSSTEXT:
                    return element(by.cssContainingText(locatorValue, expectedText));
                    break;
                case customLocators.PARTIALLINKTEXT:
                    return element(by.partialLinkText(locatorValue));
                    break;
                case customLocators.PARTIALBUTTONTEXT:
                    return element(by.partialButtonText(locatorValue));
                    break;
                default:
                    logger.info('browser : ' + locatorType + ' is invalid, Please check the selector name..');
            }
        }
```